# mongodb how to find exclude areas, $geoExclusion?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geo

There is a $geoIntersection. But does it exist something similar to $geoExclusion?
I would like to find polygons that do not intersect to certain areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$not`:

```
db.places.find({ "loc" : { "$not" : { "$geoIntersects" : { 
    "$geometry" : { 
        "type" : "Polygon", 
        "coordinates" : [[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]] 
    } 
} } } })
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that unline `$near` or `$nearSphere` the `$geoIntersects` and `$geoWitin` operators do not require an index.  The `$not` exclusion here negates the index and makes the selection brute force through the collection. But the logic of selecting the "inverse" is sound.